# Non linear compact map

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compact-operators

Suppose to have two Banach spaces $E$ and $F$, with $E$ reflexive. Suppose to have a continuous map $T:E \to F$ which maps bounded subsets into precompact subsets. $T$ is not assumed to be linear.
Finally, suppose to have a sequence $(e_n)_n\subset E$ weakly convergent to $e\in E$.

Then, up to subsequences, $T(e_n)$ converges strongly to $T(e)$.

Is it correct? How can I prove it? Can I drop the reflexivity assumption?

Comment: I'd try to prove that in reflexive spaces weakly convergent sequences are bounded (it's true in Hilbert spaces, which is reflexive). If we have it, then the rest of the proof is evident.

Comment: If $T$ is linear this is correct even for nonreflexive spaces.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Apologies if I'm misunderstanding what you're saying, but weakly convergent sequences are necessarily bounded even in general normed spaces by the Banach–Steinhaus theorem.

Comment: @anonymous you are right.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true I'm afraid. Weak convergence and nonlinearity are fundamentally incompatible(*).

Let $F$ be finite-dimensional. Then any continuous (nonlinear) operator is bounded and thus compact. But it will not generally translate weakly convergent sequences into (weakly) convergent sequences.

Consider, e.g., the map $T \colon E \to \mathbb R$ with $T(x) = \|x\|$. Even if $E$ is the nicest of all spaces, the sequence space $\ell^2$, you will have $e_n \xrightarrow{\sigma} 0$ as $n \to \infty$ but $T(e_n) = 1$ for every $n$.

**Update**: To motivate the claim (*) a bit: The straightforward way you prove that bounded linear operators $T \colon E \to F$ map weakly convergent sequences in $E$ to weakly convergent sequences in $F$ is by observing that $f(Tx_n) = (f \circ T)(x_n)$ and that $f \circ T \in F'$. This approach takes you nowhere if $T$ is nonlinear.